# vgextend fails with error code 5

Tags: lvm

So I'm currently using LVM to manage my hard drives, and I'm trying to add my new 2 TB drive to a volume group using vgextend. However, when I run the command, it returns with an error message saying "Command failed with status code 5", and the return code of the command is also 5.

I looked up the code on Google, and it supposedly means that there was an "error checking the existence of the volume group". However, when I run vgdisplay my volume group comes up as expected. Also, I tried running vgextend with a volume group name that I know does not exist, and it comes up with the same error code but a different message: "Volume group not found". This is as expected, but now I have no idea what the error is.

Here is a log file from when I run vgextend -vvvv: http://paste.ubuntu.com/635361/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out my root partition was mounted read-only, which caused the error.

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue. Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.